# File GDB to SDE Database using FME

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form, file-geodatabase, fmeobjects

I'm currently stuck in my FME Workspace script. Ideally, I'm reading from a file geodatabase and will update the SDE database in SQL server. I have CRC calculators to check for the changes in the Attributes and Coordinates and if the 2 CRC values are different then i will use the data from the File GDB to update the  SDE database.

This is a screenshot of my workspace:
[image]

The issue that i am encoutering is it always updates the data because the geometries being stored in the SDE database is not the same with the geometries in the File GDB.

I modified the SDE writer feature type to match the X,Y Origin and scale  from the File GDB feature class and disabled the "Simplify geometry" but the coordinates stored in the SDE Database are still changing.
[image]

These are the coordinates from the File GDB and the coordinates stored in the SDE Database:
[image]

Also both the SDE and File GDB have the same spatial reference.

I am quite stumped about this. Tried alot of things but it still automatically changes the coordinates when saved to the SDE database.

Any ideas will absolutely be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that before your CRC calculators you put in a [Coordinate Rounder](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#Transformers/coordinaterounder.htm) to eliminate the floating point differences.  I would also save a copy of the original geometry as a WKB or something ([Geometry Extractor](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#Transformers/geometryextractor.htm%3FTocPath%3DFME%20Transformers%7CAll%20Workbench%20Transformers%7C_____145) and [Geometry Replacer](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#Transformers/geometryextractor.htm%3FTocPath%3DFME%20Transformers%7CAll%20Workbench%20Transformers%7C_____145)) before rounding so that can be used to write to SDE database.

Unfortunately you can't really eliminate the changes to the coordinates in SQL Server and it uses FLOATs to store the coordinates.  These are an approximate datatype.  I suspect FGDBs do as well, but with a different precision.  Arc generally deals with this by having a tolerance.  FME is a bit more literal.

I would also look at changing the extents in your file geodatabase to fit closer to the extents of your data.  -400 to 400 is likely to be way more than what you will ever have in your data.

Comment: Thanks Micky! this solved my issue, although it is still rounding it when saved to the SDE database but I can still have the correct CRC value.